# Jira plugin installation

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I just finished developing my first Jira plugin(it's a report plugin). It is working perfectly in the development environment(when I run with atlas-run) but when I install in on the Jira Server it crashes...

The instalation process is done succesfully bun when a want to open my report it doesn't work.

This is the error I get:

```
    com.google.template.soy.tofu.SoyTofuException: When evaluating "$field.configurationHtml": Failed to invoke accessor getConfigurationHtml on instance of class 


    com.google.template.soy.tofu.SoyTofuException: When evaluating "$field.configurationHtml": Failed to invoke accessor getConfigurationHtml on instance of class com.atlassian.jira.plugin.corereports.web.action.ConfigureReport$ObjectConfigurationField
    at JIRA.Templates.Core.Reports.Configure.objectConfiguration(configurereport.soy:146) [?:?]
    at JIRA.Templates.Core.Reports.Configure.configure(configurereport.soy:74) [?:?]
    at com.google.template.soy.tofu.internal.BaseTofu.renderMainHelper(BaseTofu.java:369) [?:?]
    at com.google.template.soy.tofu.internal.BaseTofu.renderMain(BaseTofu.java:322) [?:?]
    at com.google.template.soy.tofu.internal.BaseTofu.access$100(BaseTofu.java:66) [?:?]
    at com.google.template.soy.tofu.internal.BaseTofu$RendererImpl.render(BaseTofu.java:476) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.soy.impl.DefaultSoyManager.render(DefaultSoyManager.java:154) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.soy.impl.DefaultSoyTemplateRenderer.render(DefaultSoyTemplateRenderer.java:45) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.soy.impl.DefaultSoyTemplateRenderer.render(DefaultSoyTemplateRenderer.java:39) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.dispatcher.JiraSoyViewDispatcher.render(JiraSoyViewDispatcher.java:48) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.dispatcher.JiraSoyViewDispatcher.dispatch(JiraSoyViewDispatcher.java:38) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.dispatcher.JiraWebworkViewDispatcher.dispatchViaSoyView(JiraWebworkViewDispatcher.java:120) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.dispatcher.JiraWebworkViewDispatcher.dispatchView(JiraWebworkViewDispatcher.java:54) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.dispatcher.JiraWebworkActionDispatcher.service(JiraWebworkActionDispatcher.java:178) [classes/:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraLastFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(JiraLastFilter.java:39) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:74) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraLastFilter.doFilter(JiraLastFilter.java:36) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.HeaderSanitisingFilter.doFilter(HeaderSanitisingFilter.java:37) [atlassian-core-7.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.onboarding.postsetup.ui.PostSetupAnnouncementsFilter.doFilter(PostSetupAnnouncementsFilter.java:51) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.tzdetect.IncludeResourcesFilter.doFilter(IncludeResourcesFilter.java:77) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.baseurl.IncludeResourcesFilter.doFilter(IncludeResourcesFilter.java:34) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32) [atlassian-core-7.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.greenhopper.jira.filters.ClassicBoardRouter.doFilter(ClassicBoardRouter.java:62) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.mywork.client.filter.ServingRequestsFilter.doFilter(ServingRequestsFilter.java:32) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.plugin.mobile.web.filter.MobileAppRequestFilter.doFilter(MobileAppRequestFilter.java:37) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32) [atlassian-core-7.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.plugin.mobile.login.MobileLoginSuccessFilter.doFilter(MobileLoginSuccessFilter.java:54) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.diagnostics.internal.platform.monitor.http.HttpRequestMonitoringFilter.doFilter(HttpRequestMonitoringFilter.java:55) [atlassian-diagnostics-platform-1.1.10.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.UniversalAnalyticsFilter.doFilter(UniversalAnalyticsFilter.java:75) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:33) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.plugin.corereports.filters.ReportKeyRewriter.doFilter(ReportKeyRewriter.java:48) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32) [atlassian-core-7.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.request.RedirectInterceptingFilter.doFilter(RedirectInterceptingFilter.java:21) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32) [atlassian-core-7.0.2.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.java:32) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.java:55) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.java:80) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.java:51) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.labs.botkiller.BotKillerFilter.doFilter(BotKillerFilter.java:36) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:55) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:43) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.MobileAppRequestFilter.doFilter(MobileAppRequestFilter.java:36) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32) [atlassian-core-7.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.accesslog.AccessLogFilter.executeRequest(AccessLogFilter.java:93) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.accesslog.AccessLogFilter.doFilter(AccessLogFilter.java:79) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at com.atlassian.jira.security.xsrf.XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.doFilter(XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.java:46) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:181) [sitemesh-2.5-atlassian-11.jar:?]
    at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:85) [sitemesh-2.5-atlassian-11.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.SitemeshPageFilter.doFilter(SitemeshPageFilter.java:112) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.pagebuilder.PageBuilderFilter.doFilter(PageBuilderFilter.java:81) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.CommittedResponseHtmlErrorRecoveryFilter.doFilter(CommittedResponseHtmlErrorRecoveryFilter.java:55) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:55) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:43) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.MauEventFilter.doFilter(MauEventFilter.java:49) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32) [atlassian-core-7.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraSecurityFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(JiraSecurityFilter.java:66) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:242) [atlassian-seraph-4.0.4.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraSecurityFilter.doFilter(JiraSecurityFilter.java:64) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at com.atlassian.security.auth.trustedapps.filter.TrustedApplicationsFilter.doFilter(TrustedApplicationsFilter.java:94) [atlassian-trusted-apps-core-5.0.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.BaseLoginFilter.doFilter(BaseLoginFilter.java:148) [atlassian-seraph-4.0.4.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraLoginFilter.doFilter(JiraLoginFilter.java:77) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32) [atlassian-core-7.0.2.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.42]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider.internal.servlet.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:67) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-5.2.3-96cf760eb.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56) [?:?]
```

Can someone help me please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Update Jira version in pom.xml to match the Production env version, and try to run your plugin. Share your results

Comment: Hi @AbdulKarim, I tried to update the version, doesn't work , the problem is that I am using a bean 'projectRapidViewServiceImpl', it is working in version 7.13 but I think it was removed from newer versions of Jira...

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'projectRapidViewServiceImpl' available`